# Query/Search in SelectList ViewBag with Linq/Lambda expression rather than using foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, viewbag, selectlist

In controller the selectlist's Viewbag is:

```
ViewBag.DSUB = new SelectList(db.SUBJECTs, "SCODE", "SUBJECT1");
```

And in view I can check it with certain value by foreach lopp. I need to do the same thing with Linq Comprehension/ Lambda expression to make my code more readable.

```
string certainStringVariable = '5';
@foreach (var DSUBName in ViewBag.DSUB)
{
    if (DSUBName.Value == certainStringVariable)
    {
    @DSUBName.Text
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate him/her who will relief me from this stuck.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  can you see and help with Briefing :)?

Comment: Why are you creating SelectList when you just want to iterate over it? Wouldn't it be simple just to use normal generic List<T>?

Comment: I am giving only one select list from many. Because I need to create a dropdownlist as well as also print the viewbag value in a table cell in the same view.

Comment: I don't understand the problem....

Answer (score 0):

```
string certainStringVariable = '5';
@foreach (var DSUBName in ((SelectList)ViewBag.DSUB).Where(a => a.Value == certainStringVariable))
{
    @DSUBName.Text
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add some explanation.